# Which HTML 5 mobile game framework to use

Tags: html, mobile, frameworks, multiplayer, 2d-games

I want to develop a multiplayer mobile game with **html5** and **js** and I am looking for some frameworks, libs, platforms or tools to make it easier. I found some but I couldnt be sure whether they provide what I need. like

- cocoonjs
- createjs
- Isogenic Game Engine

I want to develop a **real-time multiplayer** mobile game for now it will be **2d** which will be on **ios and android**. I need good documented and actively developed. If there is something which will do server-side itself it would be great :)

Any suggestion to start from?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any JS libs that will do exactly what you are expecting. You'll always need to write the server side yourself, and the same JS lib doing your server side kinda makes it client side since it's used by the game on your users device.

If you are asking for a JS lib which has built in methods to communicate with your server side that's a different story. However I'm rather sure you'll have to use a separate library for this.

As for a JS library which you can use to make your server side, try node.js. You can find a tutorial for doing some basic server stuff with node.js here: http://smartmobilestudio.com/2014/01/08/server-side-node-js-part-2/

Comment: Thank you for answer I did some research about it and what I found was the same as you said. Everyone says that I need to learn node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You can find a decent list of options at [html5gameengine](http://html5gameengine.com/).  Like @Jens Ponnet says I don't think you will find something that does everything for you, and will likely need different js libraries for specific tasks

I recommend createjs, but am biased because I work on it.  It handles asset loading, graphics, and audio for you excellently.  But you'd still need to create a game engine and server-side communication.

Good luck.

Comment: I saw that link also. And I am still thinking whether cacoonjs or createjs. But probably I will go on with createjs because of its documentation and popularity. Thank you for answer :)

Comment: People in the CreateJS community successfully use it with PhoneGap and CacoonJS, so you may end up using both.

Some have even [made plugins](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/soundjs/1633-cacoonjs-audio-plugin) to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop in JS, it doesn't matter which engine you use, you'll be able to port it to mobile using CocoonJS.

Anyway, note that a mobile isn't a PC and the higher requirements you need, more complicated will be to port it afterwards to mobile, no matter if you use CocoonJS, ejecta, or others.